# Cauchy criterion applied to series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, cauchy-sequences

I'm trying to apply de Cauchy criterion to the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 1/(zn)!$ with $z \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ in order to find an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the finite evaluation of the series up to $N$ has a accuracy of 6 decimals. In order to find this $N$, let $N\leq n<m$:

$$\sum_{i=n}^m \frac{1}{(zi)!} \leq \sum_{i=n}^m \frac{1}{(zn)!}=\frac{m-n}{(zn)!}< \frac{m}{(zn)!} < \frac{m}{(zN)!}.$$

I want the last term to be smaller than $\varepsilon > 0$, but then $N$ will be depend of $m$. Could you find a way such that $m$ doesn't appear in the last term?

Comment: Perhaps you could say for $n>0$ that $\dfrac{1}{(zn)!} \le \sum\limits_{i=n}^m\dfrac{1}{(zi)!} \le \sum\limits_{i=n}^m \dfrac{1}{(zn)!2^{i-n}} \le \dfrac{2}{(zn)!}$